# How to return multiple recordsets from stored procedure using PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I need to run a stored procedure that return 2 result sets with PowerShell. I use dbatools to do so but I could use .NET to get there. I just don't know how.

For this example, I use `exec sp_spaceused` that will return the space used in the actual database. Here's the result in SSMS:

[image: result from sp_spaceused in SSMS]

As you can see here, there are 2 result sets. Now when I run the same command in PowerShell, I can't figure how to get the next result set.

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
$conn = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance . -MultipleActiveResultSets
$query = 'exec sp_spaceused'
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $conn -Query $query
```

I'm not even sure if I used `MultipleActiveResultSets` in the right way. I can't find any good example anywhere.

Comment: `MultipleActiveResultSets` is not the right thing, that is used for executing multiple queries concurrently, and is usually a bad idea anyway. Looking at the docs, maybe `-As 'DataSet'` then you can grab individual tables out of it? I assume that's a standard ADO.Net [`DataSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I just found the answer by testing all the different `-As` options. Here's the code:

```
$conn = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance . -Database 'StackOverFlow'
$query = 'exec sp_spaceused'
$ds = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $conn -Query $query -As DataSet
foreach ($table in $ds.Tables) {
    $table | Out-String
}
```

I use `Out-String` to avoid joining objet but you could use `Out-GridView`. I also realize that I don't need to use `-MultipleActiveResultSets`.